# Criteria query returns child objects rather parent object that was requested

Tags: hibernate, mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have a problem with a hibernate criteria query. I have:

```
DetachedCriteria carCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Car.class);
List<Car> cars = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(carCriteria);

for(Car car : cars) {
System.out.println("class type " + car.getClass());
}
```

The above prints class type model.FourByFour where FourByFour extends Car. As I have specified the Car class in the DetachedCriteria, I was expecting the class type to be Car and not FourByFour.

Mapping (simplified):

```
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field" default-lazy="true" package="model">
<class name="model.Vehicle" table="VEHICLE">
<id column="VEHICLE_ID" name="id" type="long">
    <generator class="native" />
</id>

    ...

    <joined-subclass extends="model.Vehicle" name="model.Car" table="CAR">
    <key column="VEHICLE_ID" />
        ....
        <joined-subclass extends="model.Car" name="model.FourByFour" table="FOUR_BY_FOUR">
    <key column="VEHICLE_ID" />
    </joined-subclass>
</joined-subclass>
</class>
```

How can I make the object returned from the criteria query be a Car object and not the FourByFour object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for cars, and since FourByFour extends Car, a FourByFour *is a* Car, so the query also returned FourByFour instances. Hibernate queries are polymorphic. Just like when you go to a car store and they show you all their cars, even if they're SUVs, Monospaces or Hybrid cars.

To restrict to a specific class instance, you must add an additional criterion:

```
carCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("class", Car.class));
```

Comment: Makes sense! I have added this but 0 results were returned. Is "class" propertyname the actual propertyname or should I be replacing with something else?

Comment: No, class is the right property. Check the generated SQL, and check that you actually have cars that are not instances of any subclass of Car in your database.

Comment: That was it! I had instances of the subclass of Car- many thanks for your help! Super fast too!